# How to get tracking number for items using order id for an order

Tags: magento2, sales-order, fedex, shipment-tracking, dhl

I am getting the order information using

```
 $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
 $order = $objectManager->create('Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface')->get($orderid);
```

Then I am iterating the $order to get the ordered item related info.
How can I get the tracking number for those items as well?

```
 <?php foreach ($order->getAllVisibleItems() as $item): ?>
    // how to use $item to get tracking number
 <?php?>
```

I came to this this solution but this didn't work and I don't want to iterate it  `$order->getTracksCollection()` as I am already in a loop of `<?php foreach ($order->getAllVisibleItems() as $item): ?>`

```
 $tracksCollection = $order->getTracksCollection();
 foreach ($tracksCollection->getItems() as $item) {
    echo $track->getTrackNumber(); // Tracking number
 }
```

Comment: Check the below answer @summu

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this,

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$order = $objectManager->create('Magento\Sales\Model\Order')->load($orderid);
$tracksCollection = $order->getTracksCollection();
foreach ($tracksCollection->getItems() as $track) {
    $trackNumbers[] = $track->getTrackNumber();
}
```

The problem seems you're not loading order object.

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks it worked

Comment: this will give tracking number for all items of an order irrespective of it is configurable or simple type.

Comment: Can you explain it how it is connected I table level(database), I see sales_order_item has all items of an order, order_id of sales_order_item = entity_id of sales_order, but how it is connected to the tracking table i.e, sales_shipment_track

Comment: You can go to the file called order.php that reside getTracksCollection() and that will fetch tracking information from this class Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Shipment\Track\CollectionFactory